# How can I write a pointed function?

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble with the pointer and function parts. I'm asked to write the function: `char *mytoupper(char *p)` that converts the string pointed to by `p` to uppercase then `returns` `p`.

Note that I can't use the `<string.h>` functions. Is this how I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *mytoupper(char *p);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char str[100];
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    mytoupper(str);
    printf("The upercased string is: %s\n", str);
}

char mytoupper(char *p) {
    char result = *p;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if ((*p >= 'a') && (*p <= 'z')) {
            *p = *p - 32;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please help me check it. I have only been coding for a month. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Make sure the function prototype matches the definition.

Comment: Looks about right except you should be returning a `char*` (which points at the start of where `p` pointed at). Also avoid "magic numbers": instead of `32` you should use `'a' - 'A'` to get self-documenting code.

Comment: Just pointing, _return type_ in _definition_ & _declaration_ of `mytoupper()` are different. In your case `mytoupper()`  doesn't need to return anything, keep return type as `void`.

Comment: This code should not even compile as your function definition does not match the function declaration. Do you even ignore errors and run program which was compiled some time ago, before you made this mistake?

Comment: Does it work? If yes, then it's how you do it. If no, explain how.

Comment: The function `char mytoupper(char *p) {` shall be `char * mytoupper(char *p) {` as in the prototype. ` char result = *p` shall be `char * result = p`.

Comment: `if ((*p >= 'a') && (*p <= 'z'))` This is an assumption that's not supported [by the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3).  Only the character digits `'0'`-`'9'` are guaranteed to be represented consecutively in the execution character set.

Comment: Be aware that there are few (rarely used) character sets not having alphabetical characters neighbouring (e. g. EBCDIC), it won't work for these. Most character sets are ASCII compatible, but provide additional letters (with trema, accents, tilde, cedille, comma (Romanian), ...). These are not covered, as well as non-latin alphabets (e. g. cyrillic).

Comment: @AndrewHenle beginners may assume that the strings are ASCII encoded as other encodings with non consecutive letters are almost not in use nowadays (practically there is only one -  EBCDIC [and its Soviet variations] and the probability that the OP is programming using IBM mainframes is rather low). All popular coding standards ASCII, UTF-8, UTF16, UTF32  letters have consecutive codes

Comment: Hm, probably not in the sense of the task to solve, but `toupper` is not defined in `string.h`, but in `ctype.h`. So if we take the task word for word, we could use it... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is very platform-dependent:

```
while (*p != '\0') {
    if ((*p >= 'a') && (*p <= 'z')) {
        *p = *p - 32;  
    }
    p++;
}
```

Good (portable) code doesn't assume that all letters are consecutive, that there are no letters outside `a`..`z`, or that lowercase letters are all 32 less than uppercase letters.  All three of these assumptions are wrong unless you restrict yourself to the US variant of ASCII (For just a couple of examples, EBCDIC capital letters are 64 positions higher than the lowercase ones, and ASCII in non-US locales has letters such as `å` and `ø` outside the range of `a` to `z`).

Instead, we can use the facilities provided in `<ctype.h>`, specifically here `toupper()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *mytoupper(char *p);

/* use (void) when we ignore arguments */
int main(void)
{
    char str[100];
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    /* scanf("%s") is dangerous! Always */
    /* limit input length and check result */
    if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1) {
        fputs("Failed to read input!\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    mytoupper(str);
    /* spelling fixed */
    printf("The uppercased string is: %s\n", str);
}

/* Convert the string pointed to by s into uppercase.
   s must not be a null pointer */
char *mytoupper(char *const s)
{
    for (char *p = s;  *p;  ++p) {
        *p = toupper((unsigned char)*p);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Note that this fixes some of the issues in `main()`, too - see the comments.

Comment: He did not want yo use the library functions.  `*p = toupper((unsigned char)*p)` is wrong as this functions take the `int` parameter and no cast (especially to the unsigned char) is needed and conversions signed <=> unsigned should be avoided

Comment: You have not necessary multiple `return`s which make code less readable and error prone. It is safer to use the `goto` to the function exit (and IMO this is the only case where `goto` is acceptable) , as it is done for example in the Linux kernel.

Comment: The question says not to use `<string.h>`, and I've respected that -  `toupper()` is in `<ctype.h>` which is not forbidden.  And no, `goto` is not appropriate here.

Comment: your multiple return is not. It is enough to change the condition to make the code much better

Comment: It's required because `char` can be a signed type, but the `<ctype.h>` functions accept an `int`, with the note **If the value of `ch` is not representable as `unsigned char` and does not equal `EOF`, the behavior is undefined.**  So we need to make sure that negative values are coerced to `unsigned char` before being promoted to `int`.

Comment: please... This cast have no effect at all  and you completely misunderstood this remark. https://godbolt.org/g/mdMJDV

Comment: @P__J__, another option (which I've now taken) is to follow the lead of the `<string.h>` family, and insist that it's the caller's responsibilty not to pass null pointers.  Since our caller can never pass NULL, that's safe here.  :-)

Comment: The coding guidelines I met so far all rather would accept multiple returns than goto... In given case, it would just be so much easier, though, to invert the if-condition and place the loop into the if body...

Comment: @P__J__, [the argument to `toupper` needs to be converted to `unsigned char` to avoid the risk of undefined behavior](/a/21805970).  Or are you suggesting that answer is also wrong, and never been "corrected"?

Comment: This cast **does not have any effect** and does not protect against the UB, as it is has no effect in the generated code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "no effect on the generated code".  Do you mean the code that your current compiler generates?  It's quite reasonable for it to work for you without the required cast (Undefined Behaviour is *undefined*, and doing what you want is one possibility).  Unless you can prove the same for *all* compilers (including every future compiler), your claim is baseless.  Please re-read Keith Thompson's answer I linked in an earlier comment - in particular, the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: @P__J__ BTW, your Godbolt link shows two different object codes (one with `movsx` and one with `movzx`, as can be seen with this simpler diff: https://godbolt.org/g/qd686a (GCC 8.2 on x86-64).  I have to leave now; back on Monday.

Answer (score 3):

In your declaration of the function

```
char *mytoupper(char *p);
```

You say it returns `char *` (pointer to char)

In your definition you say it return a `char` only

```
char mytoupper(char *p)
```

The two definitions must match, so change it to

```
char *mytoupper(char *p)
```

and then inside the function don't store the first char; store the pointer to the first char and return that.

```
char *result = p;
....
return result;
```

Answer (score 3):

## DO NOT IGNORE ERRORS AND WARNINGS

Your code will not compile and you will get the error messages:

```
main.c:14:6: error: conflicting types for 'mytoupper'
 char mytoupper(char *p) {
      ^
main.c:3:7: note: previous declaration of 'mytoupper' was here
 char *mytoupper(char *p);
       ^
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:8:5: warning: ignoring return value of 'scanf', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     scanf("%s", str);
     ^
```

pointing exactly where the problem is.

There are another problems as well so see the corrected one (but only works if the chars are ASCII encoded)

```
char *mytoupper(char *p) 
{
    char *savedptr = p;
    if(p) 
    {
        while (*p) 
        {
            if ((*p >= 'a') && (*p <= 'z')) 
            {
                *p -= ('a' - 'A');
            }
            p++;
        }
    }
    return savedptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert all characters to upper case, then take a look on the ASCII table. As you might know, every character has an integer value. For example, A has the value 65. Therefore, iterate through all element and check if the value is higher than (int) 'a'. If so, then then substract ((int) 'a' - (int) 'A') from the character.

**Example**

```
int counter = 0;

while (p[counter] != '\0')
{
     if ((int) p[counter] >= (int) 'a')
     {
          p[counter] -= (int) 'a' - (int) 'A';
     }

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to convert these values to integers. It's simpler if everything is a `char`.

Comment: You have to consider to verify also the 'z' side!

Comment: ['A' is already an `int`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10): "An integer character constant has type `int`. ..."